# App rejected for using SMS

Tags: ios, sms

I recently had an app rejected for using SMS verification. The following is from resolution center:

> 2.22 - Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected." and "We noticed that your app restricts users by requiring SMS verification. This behavior arbitrarily restricts access to the app.

This is the infrastructure around which I built my app. Should I do email verification for login if the user doesn't have SMS? I still require users to provide a phone number to sign up. My issue isn't restricting to certain carrieres--it's restricting for people who DONT have carriers. What do you guys think is the best way to approach this??

Answer (score 1):

Restricting application use to a particular credential for sign-up is a good way to get rejected by Apple.  In the past I required a user to sign-in with a Facebook account; I used that mechanism to obviate the need to develop a user management system.  The application was initially accepted with this mechanism and then two iterations in was rejected.  Apple was adamant so I had to go ahead and develop a user management system that allowed the user to make use of the functions of my applications without a Facebook account.

To move forward I would suggest you articulate to Apple through the review process as to *why* you need to restrict the use of the application to those who don't have carriers.  They will either accept your rationale or reject it, at which point you need to rethink the functionality of your app and potentially develop a means by which those without a phone number can use your app.